# Is it possible selecting "optional" column in single query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, oledb

I have three tables:

```
// table item
+-------+-------+----------+
|  ID   |  Cat  |  SubCat  |
+-------+-------+----------+
|  A001 |  001  |    001   |
+-------+-------+----------+
|  A002 |  001  |    000   |
+-------+-------+----------+

// table category
+-------+-------------+
|  ID   |  CatName    |
+-------+-------------+
|  001  |  MyCategory |
+-------+-------------+

// table subcategory
+-------+--------+---------------+
|  ID   |  CatID | SubCatName    |
+-------+------------------------+
|  001  |   001  | MySubCategory |
+-------+--------+---------------+
```

`Cat` means the category id the item belongs to

`SubCat` means the sub-category id the item belongs to

`SubCat` is optional, if no sub-category, `0` will be filled

I try to query:

```
select [Item].[ID], [Category].[CatName], [Subcategory].[SubCatName]
from [Item],
     [Category],
     [Subcategory]
where [Item].[Cat] = [Category].[ID]
  and [Item].[SubCat] = [Subcategory].[ID]
```

This will successfully select record `A001`,  which is returns `"A001", "MyCategory", "MySubCategory"`

But I want to select record `A002` too, since `SubCat` is optional field

e.g. `"A002", "MyCategory", "N/A"`

I tried to use `CASE`, but seems access didn't support it.

Is there any way to do this within single SQL query, for example using `JOIN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select [Item].[ID], [Category].[CatName], [Subcategory].[SubCatName]
from ([Item] INNER JOIN
      [Category]
      on [Item].[Cat] = [Category].[ID]
     ) LEFT JOIN
     [Subcategory] 
     on [Item].[SubCat] = [Subcategory].[ID];
```

You should also learn to use explicit `JOIN` syntax, rather than commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: how about if field is `000` which should return default category name (something like `N/A`)

Comment: @user3896501 . . . That is a separate question, which I don't fully understand.  I'm pretty sure the answer involves either `nz()` or `iif()`, but I"m not sure what the exactly logic is.

Comment: I got syntax error in your SQL, does it works with access database?

Comment: I want to query Item, then return item id with its category & subcategory name, but subcategory is optional, when item subcat = 0 then subcategory name return "N/A" otherwise return normal name